# Meaning of "how"

Tags: meaning

I'm suddenly a bit confused about the meaning of how according to context. I wonder whether my thinking is correct.

> ‎a. How do you love me?
>
> b. How does it cost?
>
> c. How do you want me?
>
> d. How do you like the coffee?
>
> e. How do you like this hat?

Can these sentences above mean either 1 or 2 below according to context?

> a1. To what extent do you love me?
>
> a2. In what way do you love me?
>
> b1 To what extent does it cost?
>
> b2 In what way does it cost?
>
> c1 To what extent do you want me?
>
> c2 In what way do you want me?
>
> d1 To what extent do you like the coffee?
>
> d2 In what way do you like the coffee?
>
> e1 To what extent do you like this hat?
>
> e2 In what way do you like this hat?

Answer (score 1):

Of the five examples in the question, only the last two mean "to what extent".

I would take the others to mean

> a. Why do you love me? (although the intent of the question is unclear)
>
> b. What was its price? (should be "how **much** . . .").
>
> c. What sexual activity would you like?

In every case, adding **much** to the question would be a lot clearer, "How much...", and in some cases change its meaning, such as in **c.**

---

**Edit**

Note that "to what extent" has a similar meaning to "how much" but it isn't used as often, and won't apply in some situations, such as "to what extent is the price?"

These two sentences ask two quite different questions

> How did you do it?
>   How much did you do it?

to which the answers might be respectively

> By reading a book from the library.
>   I did it every week.

So it's important to get the phrasing right to ask a clear question.

---

Similary these two sentences:

> How do you want me?
>   How much do you want me?

ask quite different things and might receive quite different answers

> Let's try a sex position in this book.
>   I want you more than words can say.

---

In the case of questions like

> How do you like the coffee?
>   How do you like this hat?

It's quite clear what is being asked and that one of these two answers is incorrect

> By the use of my cognitive abilities.
>   I like it very much.

This is because of the [ellipsis](https://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/article/ellipsis), which is omitting the word **much** which should be in the sentence

> How **much** do you like the coffee?
>   How **much** do you like this hat?

By leaving out the word **much** the sentence is unambiguous.

---

Leaving out the word **much** when it is intended does not always produce a meaningful question

> How does it cost?

makes no sense at all unless **much** is added

> How much does it cost?

Why not? There are no real hard and fast rules to a language, and that is by usage, which is a little different from the other examples which are value judgments, not facts such as

> It cost £100.

Comment: It must be very helpful for me and English learners to explain why "how" in a,b,c in my question cannot be interpreted to mean "to what extent'.

Comment: Think of the use of "how" in questions like "How did you do it?" and you'll see the ambiguity. That question has nothing to do with "extent". The question "How **much** do you want me?" is completely different from "How do you want me?"

Comment: I cannot see even a little bit of ambiguity of "how did you do it". Shouldn't you have written "you won't see the ambiguity", not "you'll see the ambiguity"?

Comment: I'll add some more to the answer soon...

Comment: Isn't there much difference in meaning between "How does it cost?" and "How much does it cost?"?

Comment: There is a great deal of difference: "How does it cost" isn't meaningful. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Ok then, to sum up,

According to context, can **"how do you like the coffee/the hat"** mean the same thing as **"how much do you like the coffee/the hat"**?

Comment: No, as the answer says, leaving out "much" can mean something quite different, but in those two particular examples, is *unlikely* to mean anything else. So to sum up - as an English learner, don't leave out the word "much" if that is what you mean, otherwise you'll be saying peculiar sentences like some of those in the question.

Comment: As a last check, can d and e mean the same thing as d1 and e1 according to context?

Comment: IMO a2, b (neither), c2, d1, e1. Although saying "to what extent" sounds a bit pretentious.

Comment: haha, it's so interesting. I've heard from a native speaker d and e don't mean d1 and e1. They say d1 and e1 mean "how much do you like the coffee and hat", so they cannot be the same as d1 and e1 in meaning.

Comment: @Floret That *is* the same meaning. "To what extent do you like the hat" means "How much do you like the hat."

Comment: I think *How much do you like this hat* implies you just want the degree/extent the person likes the hat (a little/a bit/a lot/very much/etc). However, *How do you like this hat* could also illicit comments such as *It's a bit blue* or *It's got lots of feathers* rather than purely the extent the person likes the hat. Similarly - *How do you like the coffee?* could also illicit comments such as *it needs more sugar* or *it's a bit strong* rather than purely the extent that the person likes the coffee. Also consider the difference when you remove **much** from *How much do you like coffee?*

Comment: @Smock don't... I thought about "How do you like your coffee" but the question is hard to answer even without going there.